# Syncfusion for Angular - Theme toggling: any straightforward approach to toggle between normal/dark theme?

Tags: angular, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I found this solution in Syncfusion Knowledge base forum.
[Knowledge base provided approach](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10868/how-to-load-themes-dynamically-in-syncfusion-components)

**HTML**

```
<head>

    //...
    <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css" rel="stylesheet">

    //add style tag for dynamic theme change
    <style id="theme"></style> 

</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
    //...
    </div> 
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function(e) {
     if (e && e.value) {
           let ajax: Ajax = new Ajax('assets/styles/' + e.value + '.css', 'GET', true);
           ajax.send().then((result: any) => {
                 let styleTag = document.getElementById('theme');
                 styleTag.innerHTML=`/*${e.itemData.value}*/` + result;     
           });
      }
}
```

Requirement is to change the theme of all Syncfusion components in the app at run time,
eg: a darkmode button will toggle material.css to material-dark.css at runtime
Looking for opinion on better/simpler approach.

Comment: You could use javascript to achieve that with the command: `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--your-variable', '#YOURCOLOR');` 
Instead of having multiple css files, you'll just need to have multiple configurations for all your themes (IE: light, dark, green, ...)

Comment: I'm using third-party components. In my case its Syncfusion. They provide set of themes out of the box for each component. I guess switching CSS at runtime is more convenient in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suspect that you want to change the theme from material.css to material-dark.css using the button for the Syncfusion component. We have created a simple sample using the button method to change the theme from material.css to material-dark.css.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hufrxk?file=index.js

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Here is some (simplified) code I use to allow the user to switch between themes using a drop-down.
In my case, I use Syncfusion JS2 components, but the principle is the same.

```
findlinkhref = document.getElementById("myLinkId").href;
    
var dropDown = new ej.dropdowns.DropDownList({
      index: dropDownIndex,
      width: 115,
      dataSource: [
        { value: "material-dark", text: "Mat-Dark" },
        { value: "material", text: "Material" }
      ],
      change: function(args) {        
        var findlink = document.getElementById("myLinkId");         
        if (args.itemData.value == "material" && findlink.href != "https://.../material.min.css") {
          findlink.href = "https://.../material.min.css"; 
        } else if (args.itemData.value == "material-dark" && findlink.href != "https://.../material-dark.min.css") {   
          findlink.href = "https://.../material-dark.min.css";
        } 
      }
    });
    dropDown.appendTo("#theme-dropdown");
```

In the Header of the page I have the following CSS with an ID of "myLinkId":

```
<link id="myLinkId" href="https://.../material-dark.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: What about storing CSS files in assets/styles folder (in anguler) and use JS to switch between them ?
IE: in index.html
<link id="syncfusion-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/material.css">

then use JS to change href. Is that possible, i doubt about serving css from assets/styles folder

Comment: THe <...> in the href paths referenced in my sample code stand for <whatever your path is>. Of course, you are free to use whatever path to the location of your css files.